# Textarea (Rich Text) stripping html/form (paypal donate code)

Tags: richtext, textarea

The field strips the 'form/action' tags that are used for the Paypal link/button. Because of this the button is not a clicking link.
Is there any way i can prevent this?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank"><input name="cmd" value="_xclick" type="hidden"><input name="business" value="my@email.com" type="hidden"><input name="item_name" type="hidden"><input name="currency_code" value="USD" type="hidden"><input name="amount" type="hidden"><input src="/images/paypal.jpg" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" type="image"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this in 2.9.0 and could only recreate a edit_entry issue.

You have to click on the "View Code" button before pasting in a form in a Rich Textarea. This will work, and the form should populate when the entry is display in a template. However, when you go edit that entry, the form tag will be stripped out. Can you verify you are also having this issue?

Also, I heartily suggest getting WYGWAM.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wygwam

It's $29 bucks, I've used it to paste forms/all sorts of HTML code into an enhanced Textarea. Just make your employer buy it for you (I am in no way associated with WYGWAM and make no money from that Addon [well, except for doing a good job at my regular engineering job, which pays me]).

Comment: Yeah it works, but going back into the entry to edit it removes the code.
My client is likely to edit the page at some point and receiving donations is quite important to them.

I normally use WYGWAM on all builds, but in this case it is a non-profit charity and expenditure is limited (low Aussie dollar atm doesn't help! AU$40)

Comment: Any reason why you can't create a simple textarea field to hold the button code?

Comment: That seems very doable, but quite hacky. It will also confuse content editors (non-developers) who are asked to copy and paste code, or use a third party accessories that paste the code for them. The reasons are endless, but it's not a bad work around.